# Wowza Streaming from/to mobile devices

Tags: android, wowza

I'm developing a mobile app that stream video and audio to wowza server engine ,I have used GoCode (wowza sdk for mobile android and ios) for upstream , for the downstream i have used two solutions 
   -VideoView : in this solution we use RTSP 
   -PLDroidPlayer :in this solution we use TRMP

all the solution works , but VideoView(RTSP) take more than 10 seconds to stat streaming from the server when RTMP take 2 seconds.
I want to use WebView if there is a solution to reduce this 10 seconds.

I have an other question about GoCoder : when I decrease the framerate the quality become very good but the bandwidth become very hight .
the framerate is the number of the frame in the second so logically ,when we decrease the framerate it must the quality become bad and the bandwidth become not important.
there is an explication.

thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ? I wonder what solution did you end up with since im going to develop a same kind of app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HLS for streaming to mobile devices if latency is not important - there will be a delay of about 30-40 seconds, but compatibility is very good.

Comment: I need to make a video chat app so 30 seconds is not ignored